# NodeJS JSONStream returns data as one long string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, jsonstream

I have a 300k line JSON file that I'm trying to parse in Node using JSONStream. From the docs, when doing the following, I'm expecting the first 10 rows of the file to be output to the console, however I get the entire document as a string, with `\n` characters between each row:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');

var i = 0;

var stream = fs.createReadStream('test.json', {encoding: 'utf8'})


stream.pipe(JSONStream.parse('*'))

stream.on('data', function(data) {


  if(i < 10){
    console.log(i, data)
  }
  i++;
});
```

Shouldn't `JSONStream.parse("*")` be...parsing the JSON? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: how is your JSON file structured? maybe you should "address" sub objects in the parse function (and not address the root)

Comment: It's structured as JSON, not sure what room for variation there is here. `[{'key.one': 'value' ... }, ... {'key.one': 'value' ... }]`. Each object is on a new line.

Comment: maybe you should use the child operator '[]' to get each single array item (goessner.net/articles/JsonPath). The '*' probably gives you the root object/array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register the event handler on the jsonstream obj:

```
 var jsonStream = JSONStream.parse('*')
 stream.pipe(jsonStream)
 jsonStream.on('data', function(data) {
  // process data
 })
```